# log message if Api service status == 404 in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have this code in my service.js

```
function myService($http, $log) {

 var API = 'https://myapi.net/api/api.php?';
 $log.debug(API);

 return {

  getApi: function(inputValue, inputValue2) {
    return $http({
      url:API + inputValue + '=' + inputValue2,
      method:'GET'
    })
  }
 };
}
```

and in my controller:

```
vm.searchNetflix = function() {
  netflixService.getApi(vm.searchResult, vm.searchResult2).then(function(result){
    vm.ResultSearch = result.data;
    $log.log('result' + result);
  });
};
```

This 2 values "SearchResult and SearchResults" I call in input, and change the api url,

example:
 https://myapi.net/api/api.php?mySearchResult=mySearchResult2

when I type a value it returns something right,
and if I type something not valid, returns 404, or 400, if a of values is empty.

How I can valid this status, and return in my view?

Thks :)

Comment: So you're looking to capture an error state from the result of your service?

Comment: Yes, to be able to treat and give a result in the view, if my value is in wrong inputs

Answer (score 1):

Relaying the information back to your view largely depends on how your view is constructed, but the principle is to ensure that you're catching the error condition correctly.

This is similar to [an example on `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in the docs; you need to supply another method to your promise to cover the error conditions.

```
vm.searchNetflix = function() {
  netflixService.getApi(vm.searchResult, vm.searchResult2)
    .then(function(result) {
      vm.ResultSearch = result.data;
      $log.log('result' + result);
    }, function(errorResult) {
      // extract information from the errorResult here
    });
};
```

Any information you need to determine *why* the state is in error should ideally be provided in the `errorResult` object.

Comment: Thanks, you save me! :)